# What is the best shooting technique for FIFA11 / FIFA10 (inside the box)?

Tags: fifa-11, fifa-10

When I play in FIFA11 or FIFA10 online I usually get 4-5 scoring opportunities in a game where I'm 1v1 against the keeper from a through-ball. This is either coming down from the wing or in the middle of the field.

I usually miss 9/10 times from the keeper saving my shots, they rarely go over. Is there a reliable shooting technique I can use when inside the box - timing, power etc.?

Comment: I remember in FIFA 98 you could make a quick 90 degree turn and then turn back right before shooting, and score 90% of the time.  Occassionally the keeper would dive at where you were before the turn and you could walk the ball in, not needing to shoot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1v1 verses a keeper should usually be the surest opportunities to score.

The basic idea is you want to dribble the ball toward the keeper, and wait until the moment RIGHT as he charges you, but before he's in range to grab the ball. At this point choose a corner and tap the shoot button - you don't need a lot of power.

It's all about the timing - ideally, the ball is on your foot at the exact moment the keeper charges, so there's no delay from the time it takes to catch up to your dribble. That's why I like to NOT be sprinting when I'm 1v1 vs a keeper - more frequent touches means less time in between dribbles.

So a typical 1v1 would look like this:
-you receive the through ball beating the defender
-sprint toward the keeper
-STOP sprinting inside the box
-wait for the keeper to charge, then AS SOON as he takes that first step
-tap the ball into a corner.

It's something you kind of get a feel for - practice it in the 1v1 mode before the main menu, and you'll see what I'm talking about. Eventually 1v1's will be by far the easiest way to score your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the chip-shot:

```
key-combo = L1 + O
```

This works best on break-aways and should be attempted right about the 18-yard line.

As stated above, timing is everything on most of these shots.